# Check and download latest version manually in ios within the app

Tags: ios, version

I'm developing an application which will have quick version updates.
For example, today I uploaded an app with version 1.0, I made changes for the next release and after 2 days I want to upload it with version 1.1. But it seems very hard to me to always upload the new versions with changes.

So my idea is to check for version(with a service call for version check) if the version is below the latest version, I want to show an alert with a mandatory update or an optional update.

The problem is, how can I manually download the latest changes within the app without navigating to the app store.

Is it possible or is there any way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think Apple won't allow it.

Comment: You can't update the app itself. If you could then you would completely skip the Apple review process and there would be no need for the app store to manage updates.

Comment: You can check the version for a mandatory update or manual update but you can not download the latest changes without navigating to the app store.

Comment: If you only want to update data, you should re-construct you app first. But if you want to update your app design, logic ..., let user update it themselves